# Can swiftui List .refreshable refresh when you get to the bottom instead of the top?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to have a swiftUI list refresh when the user gets to the bottom of the list and tries to continue to scroll. The default behavior of .refreshable is to refresh when the user is at the top of the list and tries to scroll up (code below)

Is there a built in way to change the default behavior to make it refresh from the bottom of the list?

I tried using the default .refreshable scroll view behavior (code below)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(1..<100) { row in
                Text("Row \(row)")
            }
            .refreshable {
                print("Do your refresh work here")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No there is no built-in component for that.